Springboot application and single page app: HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed: post data not sent by browser
Configuring springboot for a single app page wasn't easy. I thought to meet a standard problem when debugging an react embedded in a springboot application. I read all the the posted questions about the topic but still cannot fix the problem.
The url and post data sent via postman hit the debug points in the app controller method and the request is successfull. That's fine. When the url rest api is fired from within the app in react by the browser, the debug point hit is the filter method which set the headers of the response, and nothing else. The controller method is not reached. That's weird.
The url and data are the same in the two cases, postman and browser requests, why controller is not reached in the second case ? Looks like the problem is within the server responding differently depending on the context. What is strange too is that the response header "Allow" does not contain the method POST.
I have added more logging, and the difference is that the post data in the browser case is not received by the server, despite the chrome console output shows it is actually sent. Indeed, i use the data showed to send it directly via postman, and the result is successfull. So how can i get more insight about the problem?
Thanks for your support in advance, Simon

In the application.yaml:
management: security: enabled: false
I have added a filter to set headers:
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;  httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  httpServletResponse.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");  httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT"); httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
Solved, there was a typo in the url in the ws request ...

what is your security / cors configuration in SpringBoot? please add formatted code

@JAsgarov In the application.yaml:
management:
security:
enabled: false
I have added a filter to set headers:
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

don't paste code into comments - add it to original question, correctly formatted. Also from your Spring Boot Application you need to set up CORS - see https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors

I would need more info, specifically - your controller code - to see that there is indeed a POST method defined. Then I would need to see the request info (currently you only posted response headers). Lastly would be good to compare that url in browser matches url in postman EXACTLY

@JAsgarov Thanks for your reply, i found the cause of the problem, the request fired from my front app is sent with a GET request instead of a POST... Now looking to fix that... :)   A lot of noise for a pretty basic error, but maybe will help other people ... The Option used in the call is "POST", so tricky problem still...

There was a typo in the url in the ws request ...
